# There is a reason why to use resumable upload when I have a stable connection?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I need to upload many files to Cloud Storage. Each file is 1MB to 1GB.
I have a stable connection.
I thought to use the [Simple Upload Api](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/multipart-upload). But 
Google recommend to use [Resumable upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload).

There is any real reason to choose `resumable upload` when I have a stable connection?

> For larger files (more than 5 MB) or less reliable network connections, use resumable upload instead
>
> https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/multipart-upload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Network problems are probably the main cause of needing to restart/resume uploads, but other problems can impact uploads too. For example, if a sudden burst of traffic causes your Internet connection to be temporarily overloaded your upload could time out; or there could be an intermittent client bug or server timeout/failure that causes your connection to be dropped. If these other kinds of failures are sufficiently infrequent you could just keep things simpler by using a non-resumable upload (and then just start over from scratch on the infrequent cases when the connection is dropped).